# Using String.format

Tags: java, android, string.format

How to use String Formatter to concatenate strings. what I tried is not working.

```
  String description = "This is description,";
   String message = "This is message";

   String result = description + " " + message; //works fine.

   //I want to replace it using String.format.
   //I tried the below code and it does not work.

   String.format(description, " ", message);
```

Expected result is `This is description This is message`

What is the right way of using `String.format`.

Thanks
   R

Comment: I will suggest use `StringBuilder` to concatenate string.

Comment: In this case, it is totally fine to concatenate with + as the compiler will convert it to a StringBuilder anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.format("%s %s", description, message);
```

The function header:

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

You have to pass the **format** and the variables to set. Take a lot at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
String.format("%s %s",description, message);
```

Comment: Thank you for that, what is the difference between %s and just %. please

Comment: %s call  toString(), % I don't know

Comment: Using just `%` does not work (with 1.7). I think it's a typo and the correct answer would be `%s %s`. I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
String description = "This is description %1$s";
String message = "This is message";
String finalText = String.format(description, message);
```

**Output :**

This is description This is message